# Integrating Topic Models in C# applications

Tags: c#, machine-learning, win-universal-app, topic-modeling

Am currently working on a uwp application in C# and would love to use topic models in my application. Apart from R.NET that provides an R platform for C# applications, are there other libraries in C# that could do justice to this?